# How to scan a two-dimensional array from a file in C?

Tags: c

I'm trying to scan a two-dimensional array from a .txt file to then use in a function that returns the average value, but it's not working. I'm also pretty new to C, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried directly putting the number of rows and columns, but nothing ever appears.

(I included stdio.h and stdlib.h)

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    FILE *f;
    int A[5][5], ave;

    if ((f = fopen("program4.txt", "r")) == NULL) {
       printf ("The file could not be opened\n");
       return 1;
    }

    readfileintomatrix(A, 2, 3, f);
    ave = averagevalue(A, 2, 3);
    printf ("The average value is %d\n", ave);

    return 0;
}

void readfileintomatrix (int M[][5], int r, int c, FILE *f) {
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < r; i++) {
        for (j = 0; i < c ; j++) {
            fscanf (f, "%d", &M[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

int averagevalue (int M[][5], int r, int c) {
    int i, j;
    int sum = 0;
    int average = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < r; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < c ; j++) {
            sum += M[i][j];
        }
    }
    average = sum/ (r*c);
    return average;
}
```

My matrix from my file was

0 2 4
6 8 10

I expect an output of 5, but I get nothing

Comment: Can you share an example txt file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop conditions in the `readfileintomatrix` function are incorrect, and so your `readfileintomatrix` function never terminates:

```
for (i = 0; i < r; i++) {
    for (j = 0; i < c ; j++) { // << should be for(j = 0; j < c; j++) instead of i < c
        fscanf (f, "%d", &M[i][j]);
    }
```

Changing this into

```
for (i = 0; i < r; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < c ; j++) { 
        fscanf (f, "%d", &M[i][j]);
    }
```

Yields the correct behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>  
#include<conio.h>  
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){  

    FILE *f;
    int A[5][5], ave;

    if  ((f = fopen("program4.txt", "r")) == NULL) {
       printf ("The file could not be opened\n");
       return 1;
    }
    printf ("The file is opened\n");
    A[5][5]=readfileintomatrix(A, 2 , 3 , f);
    ave = averagevalue(A, 2, 3);
    printf ("The average value is %d\n", ave);
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}

int readfileintomatrix(int M[][5], int r , int c ,FILE *f) {
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < r; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < c ; j++) {
            fscanf(f, "%d", &M[i][j]);
            printf("hello\n");
        }
    }

    return M;
}

int averagevalue(int M[][5], int r, int c) {
    int i, j;
    int sum = 0;
    int average = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < r; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < c ; j++) {
            sum += M[i][j];
        }
    }
    average = sum/ (r*c);
    return average;
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to fopen twice in main?

Comment: NO , it was a mistake.